# How can I define the touchUpInside action for KCFloatingActionButton?

Tags: swift, action, touch-event, floating-action-button

I want to define action for my KCFloatingActionButton. UITapGestureRecognizer is defined for the fab button in ViewController, but I want to do this action in manager class or on another page. I got the KCFloatingActionButton view, but I can't give it a click action.When I click on KCFloatingActionButton I don't want to define a new UITapGestureRecognizer with addGestureRecognizer ,I want it to take the action it is defined.

I can do this for UIButton or UIBarButtonItem as follows

button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)

barButtonItem.target?.perform(barButtonItem.action, with: nil)

How can I do this action for KCFloatingActionButton ?

Comment: `KCFloatingActionButton` post code please .. how you add tapGesture in it

Comment: I have two example 1, fabButton = KCFloatingActionButton()
        fabButton.buttonColor = Util.getColor(Colors.red1)
        fabButton.buttonImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fab_icon")
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(fabPresed(_:)))
        fabButton.addGestureRecognizer(tap).

Comment: second example is     fabButton = KCFloatingActionButton()
        fabButton.buttonColor = Util.getColor(Colors.red1)
        fabButton.plusColor = UIColor.white
        fabButton.tag = FAB_TAG
        
        var isAddItem = false
        
            let _ = fabButton.addItem(NSLocalizedString("new_visit", comment: ""),  icon: UIImage(named: "visit_fab_icon")!, buttonColor: Util.getColor(Colors.green), handler : {item in
               ...
            })
            isAddItem = true
       
        
        if isAddItem {
            fabView.addSubview(fabButton)
        }

Comment: @jawadAli I reached these views from a class and I want to have their defined actions

Comment: i didn't get your point ... and update code by editing your question .. not in the comments ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside) 


@objc func handleButtonAction(){
    //Put your logic here
}
```

The `self` in `addTarget` refers where will be the action to be executed, in this case will be in the current ViewController.

The `#selector(handleButtonAction)` is the function that will be executed when the user touch the button, in this case will be an Objective-C function (that's why is use the "#selector").

The `.touchUpInside` is the event that has to be triggered to execute the function.

And finally the function itself `@objc func handleButtonAction() {  }` will execute all the actions that you define for the touch up event.

the `@objc` attribute comes in: when you apply it to a class or method it instructs Swift to make those things available to Objective-C as well as Swift code.